# Constraint validator namespace loading from wrong namespace

Tags: validation, symfony

I am trying to make custom validator in symfony 2, but it loads from wrong namespace. Error says:

> Attempted to load class "DateChecker" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Errand\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints.

Here is my code:

MainBundle/Validator/Constraints/DateCheker.php:

```
<?php

namespace Errand\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class DateChecker extends Constraint
{
    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $message = 'some message';

    /**
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }

    /**
     * Get class constraints and properties
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTargets()
    {
        return array(self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT, self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT);
    }
}
```

MainBundle/Validator/Constraints/DateCheckerValidator.php:

```
namespace Errand\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class DateCheckerValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    /**
     * Method to validate
     *
     * @param string      $value      Property value
     *
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {

        //validation
    }
}
```

MainBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml:

```
Errand\MainBundle\Entity\Task:
    constraints:
        - Errand\MainBundle\Validator\Constraints\DateChecker: ~
```

Comment: Did you try clear cache?

Comment: Yes I did, it did not help.